# How do I change my sponsors?

Tags: grid-2

So I hit the randomize button when creating sponsors for my car and I've completed two of these challenges, but I cannot see a way to change them.

Do I need to complete all three challenges before I am allowed to change them?

I am trying to change them from the my vehicle menu, under sponsorships.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not possible to change your sponsors at will, and completing the sponsor objectives will not allow you to change the sponsors either.

You are granted the opportunity to change your sponsors at the start of each World Racing Series season and during this time you're normally offered additional sponsors and locations on your car to place sponsor logos.

You can change your sponsors on the 'My Vehicles' menu under 'Customise Player Livery' on the 'Sponsors' screen.

Comment: Yeah. I was just going to post that!

Comment: Looks like you're right. The sponsors are locked per tier. So choose wisely!

Answer (score 0):

On PC you can remove the cars/decals directory in the game folder, but the game won't be able to save after this (I lost like 1.5 hours of game...). But the other solution is to edit all textures files and to import a transparent DDS texture. You can use Ryder PSSG Editor to edit all PSSG files and Paint.NET to make a transparent DDS to import, and a good macro to do this on all the decals files.

However I've done a little pack with transparent sponsors so you can use it directly, just unrar the file and merge the cars/decals folder with the downloaded folder : http://www.mediafire.com/download/4222c8lhiy9p3dl/decals.rar

Comment: This answer came from here - for reference, http://steamcommunity.com/app/44350/discussions/0/864971287693655369/